# captcha in smarty doesn't work

Tags: php, smarty, captcha

I have this problem with smarty, I tried to add a captcha in smarty but I can't see the way of make it work, basically the error comes when i try to show the captcha image, in a normal php file I could embed this php script:

```
<?php 
    $SampleCaptcha = new Captcha("SampleCaptcha");
    $SampleCaptcha->UserInputID = "CaptchaCode";
    echo $SampleCaptcha->Html();
?>
```

But for smarty I did this:

```
$SampleCaptcha = new Captcha("SampleCaptcha");
$SampleCaptcha->UserInputID = "CaptchaCode";
$captcha=$SampleCaptcha->Html();
$sy->assign('captcha', $captcha);
```

The think is that the variable captcha does print the whole html to show the captcha but when it prints the image attr src it does it in php still.

```
<img alt="CAPTCHA" src="botdetect.php?get=image&amp;c=samplecaptcha&amp;t=da491a96235a0d9f5fbeb0d7c0accc89" id="SampleCaptcha_CaptchaImage" class="LBD_CaptchaImage">
```

I tried to use a smarty plugin function but it does the same.

Any expert in smarty may know the answer.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php). 
It may help you as this site has good examples across different platforms.